# How to add multiple simulation plot lines to plot generated with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I add multiple plot lines (as thin blue lines) to the existing `ggplot` code shown in the code at the bottom of this post and include in the legend "Simulations", for the simulation runs housed in my data frame `simPaths_df`? The simulations begin in period 500. That `simPaths_df` data frame has a single "x" column for the time period, and the multiple y-axis simulation outputs are in the columns to the right in the data frame labeled y1, y2... etc.

Sorry for what appears to be long code. The actual code is quite short, but the `ggplot` section is long and tortured because I'm not very familiar with `ggplot`. I'm open to any suggestions for simplifying this mess!

The below image shows what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(survival)

lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(time1 = ifelse(time >= 500, 500, time)) %>% 
  mutate(status1 = ifelse(status == 2 & time >= 500, 1, status))

weibCurve <- function(time, survregCoefs) {exp(-(time/exp(survregCoefs[1]))^exp(-survregCoefs[2]))}

fit1 <- survreg(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)

lung1.survfit <- survfit(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)
lung1.df <- data.frame(time = lung1.survfit$time, 
                       survival = lung1.survfit$surv, 
                       upper_95 = lung1.survfit$upper, 
                       lower_95 = lung1.survfit$lower)

# generate simulation paths
n_simulations <- 10
simPaths <- data.frame(x = seq(from = 500, to = 1000, by = 5))
simPathList <- lapply(1:n_simulations, function(i) {
  newCoef <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, fit1$icoef, vcov(fit1))
  y <- weibCurve(simPaths$x, newCoef)
  simPaths[[paste0("y", i)]] <- y
  simPaths
})

simPaths_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "x", all = TRUE), simPathList)

lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1), fill  = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "Historical data"), size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Survival probability", color = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "grey50"), 
                     labels = c("Historical data", "Weibull distribution fit", "Confidence intervals")) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few changes to make this happen:

- Fix a typo, `"Confidence Interval"` -> `"...vals"`
- I recommend named values in `scale_color_manual` instead of values and labels; it should be the same, I've found myself in do-loops in the past where the resolution was to do this.
- Pivot/reshape the `simPaths_df` data so that it is *longer*.

```r
simPaths_df_long <- pivot_longer(simPaths_df, -x, names_to = "sim", values_to = "survival")
simPaths_df_long
# # A tibble: 1,010 × 3
#        x sim   survival
#    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#  1   500 y1       0.282
#  2   500 y2       0.269
#  3   500 y3       0.291
#  4   500 y4       0.260
#  5   500 y5       0.271
#  6   500 y6       0.308
#  7   500 y7       0.294
#  8   500 y8       0.284
#  9   500 y9       0.335
# 10   500 y10      0.289
# # ℹ 1,000 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1), fill  = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "Historical data"), linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Survival probability", color = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Historical data"="blue", "Weibull distribution fit"="red", "Confidence interval"="grey50", "Simulations"="lightblue")) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, group = sim, color = "Simulations"), data=simPaths_df_long)
```

[image]

Order matters. If you want the blue lines to be more background, and "below" all other elements, then place it (say) before the first `geom_line`, such as

```r
lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, group = sim, color = "Simulations"), data=simPaths_df_long) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1), fill  = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "Historical data"), linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Survival probability", color = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Historical data"="blue", "Weibull distribution fit"="red", "Confidence interval"="grey50", "Simulations"="lightblue")) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(MASS)
  library(survival)
})

theme_so_q76146318 <- function(){ 
  theme_classic(base_size = 10) %+replace%    #
    theme(
      legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), 
      legend.justification = c(1, 1),
      legend.title.align = 0.5, 
      legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
      legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), 
      legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
      legend.text = element_text(size = 10)
    )
}



lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(time1 = ifelse(time >= 500, 500, time)) %>% 
  mutate(status1 = ifelse(status == 2 & time >= 500, 1, status))

weibCurve <- function(time, survregCoefs) {
  exp(-(time/exp(survregCoefs[1]))^exp(-survregCoefs[2]))
}

fit1 <- survreg(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)

lung1.survfit <- survfit(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)
lung1.df <- data.frame(time = lung1.survfit$time, 
                       survival = lung1.survfit$surv, 
                       upper_95 = lung1.survfit$upper, 
                       lower_95 = lung1.survfit$lower)

# generate simulation paths
n_simulations <- 10
simPaths <- data.frame(x = seq(from = 500, to = 1500, by = 5))
simPathList <- lapply(1:n_simulations, function(i) {
  newCoef <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, fit1$icoef, vcov(fit1))
  y <- weibCurve(simPaths$x, newCoef)
  simPaths[[paste0("y", i)]] <- y
  simPaths
})

simPaths_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "x", all = TRUE), simPathList)
simPaths_df_long <- simPaths_df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-x)

clrs <- c(`Historical data` = "blue", 
          `Weibull distribution fit` = "red", 
          `Simulations` = "#30a6e9", 
          `Confidence intervals` = "grey50")

lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "Historical data"), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(
    data = simPaths_df_long,
    mapping = aes(x, value, group = name, color = "Simulations"),
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Survival probability", color = NULL) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = clrs) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1), fill  = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  theme_so_q76146318()
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>